# How to add users to Cloud Directory via API?

Tags: single-sign-on, ibm-cloud

I am using Bluemix Single Sign On Cloud Directory from Node.js and I would like to be able to register users from the app (not manually via administration).

Is it possible? After reading the [docs](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SingleSignOn/index.html) I haven't found any API specification.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, it's not supported at this point.

Comment: Thanks. It would be a nice feature to be able to add "Register" features to the apps, not just "Login".